# Объединение массивов в один

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива (ниже привел какие могут быть, но они всегда могут быть разными)

```
   $array1 = [[1234, 543], 76, [444, 77, 87]];

   $array2 = [1221, 90, [44, 55]];
```

Подскажите, как получить из `$array1` и `$array2` вот такой один `$array3` массив

```
$array3 = [[1234, 543, 1221], [76, 90], [444, 77, 87, 44, 55]];
```

Comment: И какая тут логика? И что значит "могут быть разными"? по длине, по содержимому, по глубине, по батоности?

Comment: длинна всегда одинаковая, и глубина такая же как в примере

Comment: а логика то какая объединения? тут она совершенно не ясная....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все понятно же - каждый элемент верхнего уровня первого массива объединяется с таким же элементом второго массива.

Comment: мне просто нужно эти 2 массива склеить, в примере что массивы могут быть разные.

Comment: @u_mulder Правильно. Я просто только начал изучать php. возможно я нес могу четко обьяснить)

Comment: @u_mulder в примере объединены 1234, 543, 1221 при том, что 1221  находится на первом уровне, а  1234, 543 на втором

Comment: 1221 и `[1234, 543]` это элементы первого уровня. Один из них массив, а второй просто число.

Comment: Если в первом массиве будет вот так `[[1234], 543, [76], 444, [77], 87]` а во втором `[1221, 90, [44, 55]]`  - то какой результат должен быть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у тебя длинна разная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нетипизированные массивы. То есть по какой-то странной причине они содержат и числа и массивы чисел. PHP позволяет делать такие штуки, но вам не следует злоупотреблять этим. В большинстве случаев вы можете и должны создавать массивы со значениями одинакового типа.

Обратите внимание, что число в вашем случае эквивалентно массиву из одного числа. То есть если заменить `76` на `[76]`, то ваш алгоритм должен будет выдать тот же результат. При этом работать с одинаковыми типами гораздо проще.

Когда вы конструируете эти массивы, приводите значение к массиву. Я использую [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php), но можете сделать это foreach'ем:

```
$a = [[1234, 543], 76, [444, 77, 87]];
$b = [1221, 90, [44, 55]];
$a = array_map(fn($v) => (array) $v, $a);
$b = array_map(fn($v) => (array) $v, $b);
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Теперь все значения ваших массивов массивы и вы можете применить функцию [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) чтобы объединить их:

```
$c = array_map(fn($v1, $v2) => array_merge($v1, $v2), $a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

Может показаться, что этот метод неоптимальный, так как я сначала делаю подготовку массивов. Но в реальных задачах вы можете обеспечить типизацию на этапе конструирования исходных массивов, и тогда подготовка просто не понадобится.

Comment: спасибо большое. 
Это возможно исключение с таким массивом)

Comment: Егор, я могу конечно почитать в документации про fn($v), но можете так же просто объяснить как подготовку массивов?)

Comment: @Сергей обязатиельно почитайте. Тут всё просто, обходим исходный массив и каждый элемент [приводим](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php) к массиву. Для массивов ничего не поменяется, а отдельные числа станут массивами из одного этого числа. После этого получится что у вас все элементы массивы.

Comment: @Сергей `array_map` копирует элементы массива в новый массив, применяя указанную функцию. Можно написать аналогичный `foreach`, в котором делать приведение к массиву . А `fn() => что-то` -- это короткая запись `function() {return что-то;}`. Почитайте про [анонимные функции](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php), они как раз удобны для таких случаев.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [[1234, 543], 76, [444, 77, 87]];
$array2 = [1221, 90, [44, 55]];
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <  count($array1); ++$i) {
    $result[] = array_merge(is_array($array1[$i]) ? $array1[$i] : [$array1[$i]], is_array($array2[$i]) ? $array2[$i] : [$array2[$i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [[1234, 543], 76, [444, 77, 87]];
$array2 = [1221, 90, [44, 55]];

$array3 = [];

foreach ($array1 as $i => $value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $array3[$i] = $value;
  } else {
    $array3[$i] = array($value);
  }
}

foreach ($array2 as $i => $value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $array3[count($array1) + $i] = $value;
  } else {
    $array3[count($array1) + $i] = array($value);
  }
}

$array3 = array_merge($array3);

print_r($array3);
```